# When can keytool and java directory be different

Tags: unix, rhel

Can anyone please suggest me a scenario such that the `which java` and `which keytool` gives me two different directories(Results).

I have done a lot of google but all of them say that the keytool and the jre dir are the same so both the above commands will give the same result.

Any help will be much appreciated.